# Pyinstaller having difficulty building FileChooserListView via Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, filechooser

I'm trying to integrate a filechooser module included in kivy to allow users to go grab the file string of an input file via FileChooserListView, but when building the application through pyinstaller the application doesn't open. Anyone happen to know what the problem is? Here's an example code: works fine in pycharm, but won't open when pyinstaller builds it.

```
from os.path import exists
from threading import Thread
from sys import exit
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from os.path import sep, expanduser, dirname, splitext
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView

KV = '''

<MetaLevel>:
    rows: 2
    cols: 1
    Label:
        text: 'test text'
    Button:
        text: 'test button'
        on_press: root.popup()    

<file_popup>:
    file_chooser: file_chooser
    GridLayout:
        rows:1
        cols:1
        FileChooserListView:
            id: file_chooser
            path: r'C:\\Users'
            on_submit: root.printer()
'''

Builder.load_string(KV)

class MetaLevel(GridLayout):
    def popup(self):
        App.get_running_app().file_popup.open()

class file_popup(Popup):
    def printer(self):
        print(self.file_chooser.path)
        App.get_running_app().file_popup.dismiss()

class Cruncher(App):
    def build(self):
        self.file_popup = file_popup()
        return MetaLevel()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Cruncher().run()
```

Comment: What version pyinstaller? What does your pyinstaller command look like?

Comment: pyinstaller --version = 3.5, and I've tried pretty much every possible input, including the base "pyinstaller "C:\Users\..." " though ideally I'd use "pyinstaller --name __name__ --onedir --windowed "C:\Users\..." "

Comment: Check the warn-(script-name).txt file in the build\\(script-name) folder, I'm sure you'll see all sorts of errors.

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks.html

Comment: Weird, not my first kivy app but first time running into this issue...
regardless, okay so I'm looking at the part that says "--additional-hooks-dir=HOOKSPATH", which looks like I can use to grab the import which is being missed? Just don't know how that works exactly...

Comment: Better guide: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html#packaging-a-simple-app

Comment: pyinstaller spit out a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy_deps'. Thought I edited the .spec file appropriately, added: from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew ; Tree('C:\\Users\\<actual_user>\\PycharmProjects\\Troubleshoot\\') ; *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)] ; as requested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to make sure you have the libraries installed:
`pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew`

I did get your script to successfully build, after some digging it looks like `win32file` and specifically `win32timezone` are some hidden imports.

setup:
C:/
..Temp/
....Test/
......test.py <- Your posted code
......TEST.spec

`TEST.spec` file:

```
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:/Temp/Test/test.py'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['win32file','win32timezone'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='TEST',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False)
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('C:\\Temp\\Test\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='TEST')
```

Then running `pyinstaller C:/Temp/Test/TEST.spec`

if you want a `--onefile` (I usually do):

`TEST.spec` file:

```
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:/Temp/Test/test.py'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['win32file','win32timezone'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          [],
          name='TEST',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False)
```

Comment: Awesome! I was missing the kivy.deps library and was able to integrate that into the build and the result was a success. Thanks for the assistance.